# I need something like "using Base::*;"

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

If my base class has a function `func(int)` and my derived class has a function `func(double)`, the derived `func(double)` hides `base::func(int)`.  I can use `using` to bring the base version into the derive's list of overloads:

```
struct base
{
   void func(int);
};

struct derived : base
{
   using base::func;
   void func(double);
}
```

OK, great.  But what if I'm not sure whether `base` has a `func()` or not?  ie because I am doing template metaprogramming, I'm not actually sure what `base` is, but I want to bring its functions up to the same level - if they exist.  ie change the above example to:

```
struct base_with
{
   void func(int);
};
struct base_without
{
};

template <typename Base>
struct derived : Base
{
   using Base::func;  // if Base has a func(), I want to bring it in

   void func(double);
}

derived<base_with> testwith; // compiles
derived<base_without> testwithout;  // fails :-(
```

I need `using_if` like `boost::enable_if`.  Doesn't seem possible...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do ultimately? What is `derived<XXX>` used for?

Comment: I'm building classes that optionally implement some features, depending on how/where they are used.  Which is basically just refactoring, to a certain extent - ie instead of writing class XWithFeatureA, XWithFeatureB, XWithFeatureAandB, ... which turns into lots of boilerplate classes, I want to have X<feature_traits> where feature_traits decides which features are used.

Comment: The features being things like 'allows listeners', 'has custom setters', etc, for an objects in a system.  I don't think I could (or am allowed to) describe it enough to the point where you would be convinced that a system with optional features actually makes sense.

Comment: I'm confused, who's Tony and who's tony? Looks like a mild form of identity disorder :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're willing to put `using` statements into your derived class, I assume you know beforehands which members you *may* be interested to bring in. You can do this using `boost::enable_if`:

```
struct base_with
{
    void func(int) { cout << "func(int)" << endl; }
};

struct base_without { };

// Custom traits, by default assume func() isn't present
template <class T> struct has_func : public boost::false_type { };

template<> struct has_func<base_with> : public boost::true_type { };

// Again, if nothing else is known, assume absence of func(int)
template <typename Base, class UseFunc = void> struct derived : Base
{
    derived() { cout << "ctor: derived without" << endl; }
    void func(double) { cout << "func(double)" << endl; }
};

// Derived with func(int)
template <typename Base> struct derived<Base, typename boost::enable_if< has_func<Base> >::type> : Base
{
    using Base::func; 
    derived() { cout << "ctor: derived with" << endl; }
    void func(double) { cout << "func(double)" << endl; }
};
```

Sorry for all the printing statements. Now if you try

```
derived<base_with> testwith; 
derived<base_without> testwithout;

testwith.func(10);
testwith.func(10.5);
testwithout.func(10);
testwithout.func(10.5);
```

you should see

> ctor: derived with
>   ctor: derived without
>   func(int)
>   func(double)
>   func(double)
>   func(double)

Obviously, this is going to get *monstrous* if you try to test for several features. If I was doing such mixin-style programming, I'd probably rather use functions with different names for different features so they wouldn't hide each other - then public inheritance would be all that is needed. Interesting question in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I need to do something like

```
struct dummy_func
{
private:
   struct dumb_type {};

// interesting: does this need to be public?
public:
   // use a type that no one can see, so func is never chosen by ADT
   // and vararg just for paranoia
   void func(dumb_type, dumb_type, dumb_type,...) { };
};

...
template <typename T>
struct has_func
{
   enum { value = /* insert metaprogramming magic that checks for T::func */ }
};

template <typename Base>
struct derived : Base
{
   using enable_if<has_func<Base>, Base, dummy_func>::type::func;
   ...
};
```

grrr. Of course this doesn't work because dummy_func is not a base of `derived`.  In my case I could maybe make it derive from it when necessary.  But still barely satisfactory.

Comment: I guess that's not the same as `using Base::*`, but the `*` - 'use everything from this class', if possible, would have also given me what I wanted.